# Python: Error with libsvm.dll

Tags: python, python-2.7, runtime-error, libsvm

New to Python and SVM packages. I am currently using Python 2.7 and I have installed libsvm-3.14. However I am getting an error below.

Does anyone know what does this mean?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\PC\Desktop\Python27\MyProject\src\Main.py", line 12, in <module>
    from Classifier.svm import *
  File "C:\Users\PC\Desktop\Python27\MyProject\src\Classifier\svm.py", line 14, in <module>
    libsvm = CDLL('../windows/libsvm.dll')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 365, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
WindowsError: [Error 126] The specified module could not be found
```

Comment: Are you getting this error while installing that package or while using it?

Comment: I get this error while using it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12877167/how-do-i-install-libsvm-for-python-under-windows-7 It might be helpful to you please try once