# how to setup libsvm for python in windows ...

Tags: python, libsvm

I wanted to install libsvm for python in windows. I copied the libsvm.dll to the system32 folder in c:\Windows and I don't know to how to install the module later. I tried to copy the svm.py and svmutil.py into the C:\Python27\Scripts folder but when I do

```
import svm
```

I get the following error.

```
File "C:\Python27\Scripts\svm.py", line 22, in <module>
Exception: LIBSVM library not found.
```

Thanks ...

Comment: SOLVED: Follow my answer at here-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12877167/how-do-i-install-libsvm-for-python-under-windows-7/32358275#32358275

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't have to copy any files to your system32 folder unless you are using WindowsXP. The README for libsvm doesn't seem to have been updated for the latest versions of Windows.

Also, you shouldn't have to move the .py files from where you installed libsvm.

If you want to try to get it to work this way, you should restore the original positions of the files and add the path to libsvm to your python paths. Do this by doing something like:

import sys;
sys.path.append('/libsvm-3.18/python');

You may still run into problems even after this. There are more painless ways, however. See this question: [How do I install libsvm for python under windows 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12877167/2012659)