# python support vector machines

Tags: python, libsvm

My question is related to this one -

[How do I install libsvm for python under windows 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12877167/how-do-i-install-libsvm-for-python-under-windows-7)

I'm basically trying to get the svm library to work in python. So, I downloaded and unzipped the libsvm-3.17 folder and went into the python directory (in command prompt) and typed python. Now, when trying:

```
import svm
```

I got an error saying that libsvm was not found. Based on the question linked here, I located the libsvm.dll and copied it to C:\Windows\System32. But now when I try the same thing I get another error -

```
WindowsError: [Error 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
```

Can some one help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a 64-bit vs. 32-bit mismatch.  Perhaps you have a 64-bit OS but built the library with a 32-bit compiler.  You'll need to rebuild the library with a matched compiler, or change your OS.

Comment: Indeed.. it works on my 32 bit machine not on the 64 bit one. I ran 'make' in a couple of the folders. Is it the version of make that is 32 bit? Also, how do you catch errors like these? What was the hint?

Comment: @RohitPandey You can use a 32-bit dll in 64-bit Windows, but you need a 32-bit version of Python.

Comment: Is there a way to get the 64 bit dll?